# Elmah.Mvc not logging in MVC4 app when deployed onto Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database, elmah.mvc

I'm experiencing an issue which seems fairly common, yet I googled for similar questions but none seems up to date, so I hope someone can give a suggestion here. I cannot let ELMAH work in my mvc4 app once deployed onto an **Azure** web site, while it works fine when working locally on my development environment.

Here are the details:

1) I created an MVC4 web internet app, and added the *Elmah.MVC* NuGet package to it (the Elmah version as shown in the report page is 1.2.14706.955).

2) I completed the modifications made to my web.config by (1) by adding:

- in *appSettings*:

  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="administrator" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
- in *elmah*:

  <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />

My *DefaultConnection* string is a "standard" SqlServer string like:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now, when working locally unhandled exceptions get logged into the database. When deployed on Azure, exceptions are raised, but nothing is logged into the (Azure SQL) database.

I can successfully follow the route mywebsite/elmah both locally and remotely: only, when I try the remote route the elmah generated view shows no records, as nothing is stored in the database.

The same remote database is used for user accounts and all other purposes, so I can be sure the web app can talk to the database. Simply, no exception ever gets logged once deployed on Azure.

I created ELMAH tables and stored procs with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error]
(
    [ErrorId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Application] NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Host]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Type]        NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Source]      NVARCHAR(60)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Message]     NVARCHAR(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [User]        NVARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [StatusCode]  INT NOT NULL,
    [TimeUtc]     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Sequence]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AllXml]      NTEXT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ELMAH_Error] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ErrorId]) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [DF_ELMAH_Error_ErrorId] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [ErrorId]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ELMAH_Error_App_Time_Seq] ON [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] 
(
    [Application]   ASC,
    [TimeUtc]       DESC,
    [Sequence]      DESC
) 
GO

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        STORED PROCEDURES                                                      
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorXml]
(
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [AllXml]
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error]
    WHERE
        [ErrorId] = @ErrorId
    AND
        [Application] = @Application

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorsXml]
(
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @PageIndex INT = 0,
    @PageSize INT = 15,
    @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FirstTimeUTC DATETIME
    DECLARE @FirstSequence INT
    DECLARE @StartRow INT
    DECLARE @StartRowIndex INT

    SELECT 
        @TotalCount = COUNT(1) 
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error]
    WHERE 
        [Application] = @Application

    -- Get the ID of the first error for the requested page

    SET @StartRowIndex = @PageIndex * @PageSize + 1

    IF @StartRowIndex <= @TotalCount
    BEGIN

        SET ROWCOUNT @StartRowIndex

        SELECT  
            @FirstTimeUTC = [TimeUtc],
            @FirstSequence = [Sequence]
        FROM 
            [ELMAH_Error]
        WHERE   
            [Application] = @Application
        ORDER BY 
            [TimeUtc] DESC, 
            [Sequence] DESC

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @PageSize = 0

    END

    -- Now set the row count to the requested page size and get
    -- all records below it for the pertaining application.

    SET ROWCOUNT @PageSize

    SELECT 
        errorId     = [ErrorId], 
        application = [Application],
        host        = [Host], 
        type        = [Type],
        source      = [Source],
        message     = [Message],
        [user]      = [User],
        statusCode  = [StatusCode], 
        time        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [TimeUtc], 126) + 'Z'
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error] error
    WHERE
        [Application] = @Application
    AND
        [TimeUtc] <= @FirstTimeUTC
    AND 
        [Sequence] <= @FirstSequence
    ORDER BY
        [TimeUtc] DESC, 
        [Sequence] DESC
    FOR
        XML AUTO

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_LogError]
(
    @ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Application NVARCHAR(60),
    @Host NVARCHAR(30),
    @Type NVARCHAR(100),
    @Source NVARCHAR(60),
    @Message NVARCHAR(500),
    @User NVARCHAR(50),
    @AllXml NTEXT,
    @StatusCode INT,
    @TimeUtc DATETIME
)
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT
    INTO
        [ELMAH_Error]
        (
            [ErrorId],
            [Application],
            [Host],
            [Type],
            [Source],
            [Message],
            [User],
            [AllXml],
            [StatusCode],
            [TimeUtc]
        )
    VALUES
        (
            @ErrorId,
            @Application,
            @Host,
            @Type,
            @Source,
            @Message,
            @User,
            @AllXml,
            @StatusCode,
            @TimeUtc
        )

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For grants reason, the script u posted is not the one suitable for sql server azure.

Found solution Here ...

http://blog.redjungle.com/post/2013/01/22/Elmah-and-Azure-Using-Sql-Azure.aspx